# Add-in keeps disappearing when using append on send

Tags: javascript, outlook, office365, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I'm trying to implement append-on-send in Outlook add-in. This requires API set 1.9 but when I make the change in manifest and re-upload the add-in keeps disappearing. It's coming back if I change the set to 1.8. I'm testing it on the browser with 365. any idea?

following is the manifest with 1.9 that makes the add-in disappear

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.0" xsi:type="MailApp">
  <Id>57c79569-843d-424d-bbb4-2900628f1bfd</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>Contoso</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="Test-append"/>
  <Description DefaultValue="A template to get started."/>
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-64.png"/>
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-128.png"/>
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://www.contoso.com/help"/>
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>https://www.contoso.com</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox"/>
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.9"/>
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html"/>
        <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteItem</Permissions>  
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Edit" />
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Appointment" FormType="Edit" />
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read" />
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Appointment" FormType="Read" />
  </Rule>
  <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>
 <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
    <Requirements>
      <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.9">
        <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
      </bt:Sets>
    </Requirements>
    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <FunctionFile resid="Commands.Url" />
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageComposeCommandSurface">
            <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
              <Group id="msgComposeGroup">
                <Label resid="GroupLabel" />
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgComposeOpenPaneButton">
                  <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                    <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="ActionButton">
                  <Label resid="ActionButton.Label"/>
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="ActionButton.Label"/>
                    <Description resid="ActionButton.Tooltip"/>
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                    <FunctionName>appendDisclaimerOnSend</FunctionName>
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>

          <!-- Configure AppointmentOrganizerCommandSurface extension point to support
          append on sending a new appointment. -->

        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>
    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.16x16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-16.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.32x32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-32.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.80x80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-80.png"/>
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="Commands.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/commands.html" />
        <bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html" />
        <bt:Url id="WebViewRuntime.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/commands.html" />
        <bt:Url id="JSRuntime.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/runtime.js" />
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="GroupLabel" DefaultValue="Contoso Add-in"/>
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="Show Taskpane"/>
        <bt:String id="ActionButton.Label" DefaultValue="Perform an action"/>
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Opens a pane displaying all available properties."/>
        <bt:String id="ActionButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Perform an action when clicked."/>
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
    <ExtendedPermissions>
      <ExtendedPermission>AppendOnSend</ExtendedPermission>
    </ExtendedPermissions>
  </VersionOverrides>
</VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

manifest with 1.8 and extended permissions commented out. add-in appears again

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.0" xsi:type="MailApp">
  <Id>57c79569-843d-424d-bbb4-2900628f1bfd</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>Contoso</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="Test-append"/>
  <Description DefaultValue="A template to get started."/>
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-64.png"/>
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-128.png"/>
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://www.contoso.com/help"/>
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>https://www.contoso.com</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox"/>
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.8"/>
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html"/>
        <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteItem</Permissions>  
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Edit" />
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Appointment" FormType="Edit" />
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read" />
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Appointment" FormType="Read" />
  </Rule>
  <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>
 <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
    <Requirements>
      <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.8">
        <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
      </bt:Sets>
    </Requirements>
    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <FunctionFile resid="Commands.Url" />
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageComposeCommandSurface">
            <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
              <Group id="msgComposeGroup">
                <Label resid="GroupLabel" />
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgComposeOpenPaneButton">
                  <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                    <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="ActionButton">
                  <Label resid="ActionButton.Label"/>
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="ActionButton.Label"/>
                    <Description resid="ActionButton.Tooltip"/>
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                    <FunctionName>appendDisclaimerOnSend</FunctionName>
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>

          <!-- Configure AppointmentOrganizerCommandSurface extension point to support
          append on sending a new appointment. -->

        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>
    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.16x16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-16.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.32x32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-32.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.80x80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-80.png"/>
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="Commands.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/commands.html" />
        <bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html" />
        <bt:Url id="WebViewRuntime.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/commands.html" />
        <bt:Url id="JSRuntime.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/runtime.js" />
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="GroupLabel" DefaultValue="Contoso Add-in"/>
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="Show Taskpane"/>
        <bt:String id="ActionButton.Label" DefaultValue="Perform an action"/>
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Opens a pane displaying all available properties."/>
        <bt:String id="ActionButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Perform an action when clicked."/>
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
    <!-- <ExtendedPermissions>
      <ExtendedPermission>AppendOnSend</ExtendedPermission>
    </ExtendedPermissions> -->
  </VersionOverrides>
</VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

```css
/*
 * Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. Licensed under the MIT license.
 * See LICENSE in the project root for license information.
 */
/* global global, Office, self, window */
Office.onReady(() => {
  
});

/**
 * Shows a notification when the add-in command is executed.
 * @param event {Office.AddinCommands.Event}
 */
function action(event) {
  const message = {
    type: Office.MailboxEnums.ItemNotificationMessageType.InformationalMessage,
    message: "Performed action.",
    icon: "Icon.80x80",
    persistent: true
  };

  // Show a notification message
  Office.context.mailbox.item.notificationMessages.replaceAsync("action", message);

  // Be sure to indicate when the add-in command function is complete
  event.completed();
}

function getGlobal() {

  
  return typeof self !== "undefined" ?
    self :
    typeof window !== "undefined" ?
    window :
    typeof global !== "undefined" ?
    global :
    undefined;


}

function onsend(event) {
  // Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync("html", {
  //   asyncContext: event
  // }, checkBodyOnlyOnSendCallBack);
  // console.log('test here ');
  Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync(Office.CoercionType.Html, {
    asyncContext: event
  }, function (result) {
    console.log('test here 2');
    // console.log(result);
    var newHtml = result.value.concat("<img src='https://via.placeholder.com/1'>");
    Office.context.mailbox.item.body.setAsync(newHtml, {
      coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Html
    });
    // event.completed();

    console.log('test here 3');

    // Allow send.
    result.asyncContext.completed({
      allowEvent: true
    });
    console.log('test here 4');
  });


}

function checkBodyOnlyOnSendCallBack(asyncResult) {
  // console.log('here');
  // Allow send.
  asyncResult.asyncContext.completed({
    allowEvent: true
  });
}

function appendDisclaimerOnSend(event) {
  debugger;
  var appendText =
    '<p style = "color:blue"> <i>This and subsequent emails on the same topic are for discussion and information purposes only. Only those matters set out in a fully executed agreement are legally binding. This email may contain confidential information and should not be shared with any third party without the prior written agreement of Contoso. If you are not the intended recipient, take no action and contact the sender immediately.<br><br>Contoso Limited (company number 01624297) is a company registered in England and Wales whose registered office is at Contoso Campus, Thames Valley Park, Reading RG6 1WG</i></p>';
  /**
    *************************************************************
     Ideal Usage - Call the getBodyType API. Use the coercionType
     it returns as the parameter value below.
    *************************************************************
  */
  Office.context.mailbox.item.body.appendOnSendAsync(
    appendText, {
      coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Html
    },
    function (asyncResult) {
      console.log(asyncResult);
    }
  );

  event.completed();
}


const g = getGlobal();

// the add-in command functions need to be available in global scope
g.action = action;
g.onsend = onsend;
g.appendDisclaimerOnSend = appendDisclaimerOnSend;
```

Comment: Can you please help us with some more details?
1. What is the browser that you're using?
2. When you're trying to re-upload the manifest file are you getting any error message?
3. Are all addins getting disappeared? Or is it applicable for your particular addin only?

Comment: Sure. 1. I tested in Chrome, Firefox and edge. Add-in is disappearing in all browsers when published with 1.9 in manifest.  2. no error message on re-upload 3. only the add-in that i am working on. Like i mentioned it came back after re-uploading with 1.8 but append on send needs 1.9

Comment: Can you please mention the changes that you're making in the manifest for this?

Comment: I followed this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/append-on-send  I updated set to 1.9 added Extended permissions, version override, added action type execute function

Comment: Can you please share the 1.8 and 1.9 manifest files?

Comment: I added both manifest files and command.js file to description

Comment: Hey Kumar, we are investigating this issue and we have put it in our backlog. However, we don't have any timelines to share at this point.

Comment: Ok, Please let me know when you have any update. Thanks

Comment: Hi Kumar Garapati, 
We tried to install the addins using both the manifests which you have shared in the post. We are able to install both successfully. Please try from a different machine if possible.